# Why is `== null` preferable to `is Null`?

Tags: dart

In Dart, checking for a value to be `== null` seems similar to checking if it `is Null`. Why is the former more preferable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the type of comparison you are doing. In `== null`, you are comparing an object/primative to `null` whereas in the latter, `is Null`, `null` is an object. It makes no difference in the compiler.

`== null` is more favourable as the two being compared could be both primitives, which saves memory in the system.

Comment: Do you have a source for this statement?

Answer (score 3):

`== null` is familiar to developers coming from other popular languages.

Comment: Why does `is Null` cause a warning?

Comment: I think it's actually just a static hint, not a warning. A warning would cause checked mode to fail. I guess the hint is just there to enforce the coding style.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about static hints before.

Comment: The basic trifecta, errors cause the prod mode VM to fail compilation, warnings cause checked mode VM to throw, and hints are extra info shown by tools before compilation. Hints aren't in the language spec, they are just useful tooling.

Comment: "== null is familiar to developers coming from other popular languages " which does not allow use `is Null` as the Dart because this is not possible. The type `Null` must be internal type.

Comment: Yup. In Dart Null is just a normal class. See [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/sdk/lib/core/null.dart) for the source.

Comment: @GregLowe You say "Yup. In Dart Null is just a normal class." I am sorry, but developers does not know about this fact. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871856/what-means-in-dart-static-type-and-why-it-differs-with-runtime-type. Ha-ha-ha!

Comment: "is Null" should not cause a warning.

Comment: It doesn't cause a warning - but the analyzer provides a hint to use == instead.

Comment: If I type print(foo is Null) in the editor, I get a hint "Tests for null should be done with '== null'".

Comment: @GregLowe Smart people may not use Dart Editor because it have a lot of bugs (or by the other reason). But they needs to learn big Dart language specification because not possible write and compile Dart source code only if you know Dart grammar. Because Dart semantics is ambiguous that complicates understanding of the principles of Dart language at all (including different and contradictory type checkings mechanisms such as static and dynamic, their delegated credentials between different environments of compilation and execution).

Answer (score 2):

Using this type check in Dart not a quite correct.

```dart
if(value is Null) {
}
```

In Dart the static type of `null` is `bottom type`.

An as we know, the bottom type is a subtype of all types.

Now we test subtypes in Dart (including value of `bottom` type, `null`)

```dart
void main() {
  var subtype = new Subtype();
  var typeOfBase = new TypeOf<Base>();
  test(subtype, typeOfBase);
  test(null, typeOfBase);
}

void test(value, TypeOf typeOf) {
  var type = typeOf.type;
  var runtimeType = value.runtimeType;
  if(typeOf.isSubtypeOf(value)) {
    print("Value [$value] of type [$runtimeType] is a subtype of [$type[");
  } else {
    print("Value [$value] of type [$runtimeType] is NOT a subtype of [$type]");
  }
}

class Base {
}

class Subtype implements Base {
  String toString() => "subtype";
}

class TypeOf<T> {
  Type get type => T;

  bool isSubtypeOf(value) => value is T;
}
```

Results:

```
Value [subtype] of type [Subtype] is a subtype of [Base[
Value [null] of type [Null] is NOT a subtype of [Base]
```

So, here we can see that performing this test is not quite correct in Dart because `null` has not `bottom type` but a value of regular type `Null` which are not a `bottom` type and, of course, not a subtype of `Base` type.

So, I not recommend using `is Null` in Dart because in the future the class `Null` can be considered as deprecated and replaced by some internal implemented type as `void` or `dynamic`.

Comment: The "is" check is a dynamic check. It checks if the left-hand-side instance implements the right-hand-side type. In this case it really do check if the Null class is implemented by the null instance (which it is). The static bottom type doesn't interact with this test at all.

Comment: I'm more and more convinced that the in Dart are fewer and fewer remains advantages and more and more revealed disadvantages. To understand this need not be a genius. Simply start using it. Simply try to ask serious question. Simply try to get quality support from developers. Simply try begin to understand language without reading big specification. Simply try to wrote short code with only non-complicated SDK. Simply try to get rational reason why a lot of the some useful features requested by the community wait more than two years when they will be implemented and they still not implemented.