# What means in Dart static type and why it differs with runtime type?

Tags: null, virtual-machine, dart, bottom-type

In Dart exists two kind of types.

1. Runtime type
2. Static type

Here is proof in [Dart language specification](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.gianetx6ltsy):

The **static type** of null is bottom.

1. Runtime type of `null` is `Null`
2. Static type of `null` is `bottom`

This mean that objects in Dart can have two kind of types.

One real type that called `static` and one `virtual` type that called `runtime`.

That is, runtime type of `null` is not a `bottom` but a regular class `Null`.

```dart
class Null {
  factory Null._uninstantiable() {
    throw new UnsupportedError('class Null cannot be instantiated');
  }

  /** Returns the string `"null"`. */
  String toString() => "null";
}
```

But at the same time value with this regular runtime type `Null` can be assigned to any other type because real (static) type of the `null` is a `bottom` type.

How called this technique in Dart?

The type substitution or something different?

P.S.

This question about **static types of values** but not about static types of variables that declared with type annotations.

This is because the `null` is not a variable but `value` with `static type` of `bottom`.

P.S.

Very curious case (at least for me).

```dart
void main() {
  Null _null;
  String s = _null;
}
```

I get a warning:

```
A value of type 'Null' cannot be assigned to a variable of type 'String'
```

It is quite correct. But at the same time this works.

Сurious thing with type substitution (static and runtime).

Comment: The "null canot be assigned to string" warning seems like an error (either in the analyzer, or in the specification). It is statically determinable that all values of the Null type can be assigned to a variable of type String.

Comment: @lrn I just rely on facts.

Comment: Related issue: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16975

Answer (score 5):

The runtime type of a Dart **value** is its class.
The static type of a Dart **expression** is what the static type inference derives it to be, and it belongs to the world of static types. That world is larger than just the classes declared in a program.
The type "bottom", the type "dynamic" and the function type "int->int" are all examples of static types that do not correspond to a class.

Or in other words: values have classes, expressions have types (just as in many other languages).
There is no "static type of values" because static types exist at compile time, and values exist only at runtime [1].

The static type inference algorithm is specified in the Dart language specification. It is what it is, and all that is required of it is that it is, in some way, compatible with the runtime behavior of the program.

The static type system is a program analysis that attempts to detect likely programming errors, nothing more and nothing less. If you have a static type warning, it is considered likely, but not certain, that you have a bug. The type inference system should give few false warnings, and fail to detect few actual bugs, while also being simple enough to describe, understand and implement.

Picking "bottom" as the type of "null" is just a way to make the static type system match the "assignable" relation between types, which is what assignments check at runtime, without having to check explicitly for "Null" everywhere. 
It's just an algorithm that happen to give a useful result.

The static type does not exist at runtime. For example, the VM contains no implementation of the static type system at all.

/L

[1] Well, except for compile-time constant expressions.

Comment: In computer science, a value is an expression which cannot be evaluated any further (a normal form). Your words "values have classes, expressions have types" is not correct. Also you say  "There is no "static type of values" because static types exist at compile time, and values exist only at runtime". For example, the expression "1 + 2" is not a value as it can be reduced to the expression "3". And as I say "a value is an expression which cannot be evaluated any furthe". So, I not agree with you in many cases that, including "values have classes, expressions have types".

Comment: But if you change the term `value` to the term `instance` this will be correct. But you say not `instance` but `value`. So, I'm stating a fact. you are wrong in their judgments

Comment: "Picking" bottom "as the type of" null "is just a way ...". This is a right way. But make `Null` class visible for user code is wrong. It must be internal type or private class `_Null`. This will automatically remove all the questions why you went for a compromise because in this case expression `value is Null` will be not possible due visibility protection level of this class (or type, if it will be internal type).

Comment: If all you have is syntax, then values are expressions. For rewrite semantics, that is what you get. If you have a denotational semantics, then your syntax and your values may live in different domains.

Comment: I am not about semantics. I am about syntax. What semantic we will get when use this syntax? Your compromise make that the with the correct syntax (that identical for all kind of objects) we get different semantics with some kinds of objects. In our case with `null` value and `Null` class. But if with `null` value we have no problem than with public `Null` class with have different semantics than with all other simalar classes. Where in source code we can see that class `Null` is a bottom type? Nowhere. I can call this as compromise (different) semantics with the same syntax in source code!!!

Comment: The point was just that in computer science, values need not be expressions. It depends on the context. By all means, read "instance" instead of runtime "value". This is also all about semantics. A type validation system is a static semantic, or a static abstract interpretation, of a program. Dart has both static semantics (implemented by the analyzer) and dynamic semantic (implemented by the VM) on the same syntax. Each has its own interpretation of the expression `null`. Luckily the two agree enough that the analyzer is useful for predicting runtime errors.

Comment: It is better to have slightly more complicated syntax and more clear semantic based on this syntax than having pretty moderate syntax and and unclear semantic. This is because all possible behavior must be specified not by syntax (grammar) but by the some big specification that describes all possible behaviors in some special cases of all special types. Suffice it to recall: non extendable classes as `int` and `double`, very strange behavior of `num` class. Also class `Null` that declared (by syntax) as regular class but treated as `bottom`. And as the result we get unclear language.

Comment: You say "Each has its own interpretation of the expression null". You still have not understood me. I do not see any problems with `null`. I see a problem with the class `Null`. It has the behavior not as all the other classes despite the fact that it declared by the same syntax as all other classes. To explain this it is necessary to come up with an exceptional rules in language specification instead to understand the fact that is better be just to hide it (or at least make it private) and delete all these contradictions from specification.

Comment: And please do not explain me about different semantics (implemented by the analyzer and implemented by the VM) on the same syntax. This makes Dart language more unclear then other similar languages and hard to understood because this fact (behavior) divides one programming language called Dart on two different Dart languages. I know that you want explain me also about two different modes of execution of Dart scripts (checked and production). But this fact only devides previous two different Dart languages on other four!!! different Dart languages.

Comment: Small nit. "The static type inference algorithm is specified in the Dart language specification" I thought the spec omitted specifying any form of inference, but allows tools to use inference to provide additional hints over and above the warnings in the spec.

Comment: @GregLowe From FAQ: "Type inferencing is not something specified by the language specification, but it is something that implementations are free to do". But this is only in FAQ. But FAQ not a rules and even more so it is not a specification. It seems that you confuse the FAQ with specification. Because specification specifies language  features but not `allow` or `disallow` some features in tools such as inference because in specification this is not specified.

Comment: I have not read the FAQ, but I did check the spec before posting this comment. Have you checked it? A clue: it mentions the word infer only once. Enjoy reading ;)

Comment: @GregLowe Yes, of course. But your words "The static type inference algorithm is specified in the Dart language specification" is very strange. Where you read this? Give me link, please in specification where I can read about `the static type inference algorithm that specified in the Dart language specification`. Literally. Also, type checking is not same as the type inference.

Comment: "Where you read this?" It is a quote from the text of the answer, on which we are currently commenting. i.e. on your screen directly above this comment thread. I think the quote is incorrect.

Comment: Here, in your comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871856/what-means-in-dart-static-type-and-why-it-differs-with-runtime-type#comment33151207_21877174

Comment: @GregLowe What means word "nit"?

Comment: I admit "inference" is my word, and probably misused here. The spec talks about static type checking. It checks the type by computing a static type for each expression and checking that the types match up. The types are not as much "inferred" as "deduced".

Comment: @lrn At least look how this implemented in `dart/runtime/vm/object.h` and `dart/runtime/vm/object.cc`. Nothing magical. "The static type of null is specified to be the bottom type, however, the runtime type of null is the Null type, which we correctly return here." Also, "Check for NullType, which is only a subtype of ObjectType" return (test_kind == kIsMoreSpecificThan) || other.IsObjectClass() || other.IsNullClass(); This means that there is no such thing as static bottom type. The `Null` class only a subtype of ObjectType. It only recoginized by VM as type that has a special behavior.

Comment: @Mezoni a nit is small insect that lives in your hair and bites. In this case it is an English expression which means a tiny problem.

Comment: @lrn Also comments in Dart source code for C++ implementation `"Check for NullType, which is not a subtype of any type, but is more specific than any type. User code cannot refer to class Null, therefore, we can only encounter NullType here as the type of the null constant, which must be treated separately in 'instance of' checks."`. This means that Dart SDK does follow language s pecification becuase `class Null` declared in Dart language source code as regular class that users cannot treat as more specific type because they rely on sorce code implementation in Dart language.

Comment: @GregLowe In our language this also means that a nit is small insect that lives in your hair and bites. But in Russian this means also a nasty man, squirt. So, I not understand you a first time.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a class and write type annotations this are static types.
As type annotations are not used at runtime you can assign a value of type `Foo` to a variable of type `Bar`. Even if the static type is `Foo` the runtime type is `Bar`.

Might be wrong. I haven't taken a closer look at those matters yet.

Comment: Please, give me example that will be work in checked mode (as with `null`). Also, if you not know we add annotations to variables (value storages) but not to the values. The `null` is not declared as the variable. It is a value of some type (value of bottom type). You say "Even if the static type is Foo the runtime type is Bar". Static type of what? Static type of  value or static type of variable? I ask the question about static types of values but not about static types of variables. This is very different concepts Remember that `null` is not a variable (storage), it just a value (rvalue).